# function does not wait for DOM to load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, async-await

when I run this code I get an error saying I cannot set innerText of Null; I know this is because my function runs before my DOM fully loads in, but I do not know how to fix it.

I have tried using window.onload, and event listeners for loading, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

```
import "./styles.css";
const quoteBox = document.getElementById("App");

async function newQuote() {
  const response = await 
  fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
  const data = await response.json();
  quoteBox.innerText = data.content;
}

window.onload = newQuote();

export default function App() {
 return <div className="App" id="App"></div>;
}
```

Comment: `window.onload = newQuote();` is wrong. You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event listener. Also very unclear why you would be using window.onload in an react app.

Comment: You didn't define the event listener correctly. Instead of assigning the handler, you called it on the spot.

Comment: `window.onload = newQuote();` means "call the function `newQuote` right now and assign its return value to `window.onload`".

Comment: The real question is "Why would you do this in a React app?" This is not a React pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` so that function gets called after it is mounted.

```jsx
export default function App() {

 useEffect(() => {
    
   const quoteBox = document.getElementById("App");

   async function newQuote() {
     const response = await 
     fetch("https://api.quotable.io/random");
     const data = await response.json();
     quoteBox.innerText = data.content;
  }

  newQuote();

 }, []);

 return <div className="App" id="App"></div>;
}
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score -1):

Either add your script tag at the end of your body tag or wrap everything in a function and call it on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)